# Ask iPhone 4 to send back geotag information to server on the background

Tags: iphone, ios

I wonder if it is possible for iPhone 4:

I have a server which sends queries about the location of the phone (irregularly) via an iPhone app. Customer can choose a setting that allow the phone to send back geotag information (longitude and lattitude) in the background (without customers doing anything).

If it is possible, how should I do it? If not, what is the closest alternative available?

Thank you.

Comment: iPhone 4 or iOS 4? iPhone 3GS and 4s can als run background apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. You have to set the UIBackgroundModes flag in your Info.plist to indicate that you execute in the background.

See: [Information Property List Keys](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html)

Note that running the GPS from the background will severely impact battery life. In addition your application may be terminated at any time if the system needs the memory.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I will only send request to user's iPhone once a month at most. Is there a way to activate GPS only when needed via my app on the iPhone? My understanding is that when I send a request from server, it will be passed to the phone via notification, invoke the app, send back geotag, then exit the app. Am I right?

Comment: It is unlikely that your app will stay active for 30 days, so you will need to use a notification. However, only the user can launch your app - the notification cannot. I see no way of doing what you want.